# Javascript calcul doesn't work if number upper than 1000

Tags: javascript, arrays, division, parsefloat

I try to calculate a simple division in javascript but if my number is < 1000 
The result is not good.

Here my code :

```
var cal = parseFloat(currentAmount.toString()) / parseFloat(currencyArray[i][j].toString())
```

if `currencyArray[i][j]` equal to `1,3703` and `currentAmount = 100` my result is good `(72.98)`
but if i put `1000` my result is not good `(0.7298... )`

Comment: Why those toString ? What do you have in currentAmount ?

Comment: Please reproduce the problem in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). Right now it seems you're dealing with numbers formatted as strings but it's really a guess game.

Comment: be sure that your `currentAmount` is not represented with comma or point as thousand separator

Comment: 100 / 13703 is _not_ 72.98, so even your "good" result is actually incorrect. Why are you calling `.toString()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the particular value you get, I'm going to guess that your `currentAmount` isn't `1000` as you claim, but rather `1,000` or `1 000` or even `1'000` in some countries. When `parseFloat` gets hold of that, it sees only `1` because `,` isn't a valid character in numbers. `1 / 1.3703` is `0.7298...`.

Numbers must not have thousand separators, and decimals must be a point. (As someone who grew up in France, I know this can be confusing!)

Answer (score 0):

OK, going for a wild guess.

It looks like you're dealing with numbers as strings, with bad formatting and you have `"1 000"` or `"1,000"` and you want it to be parsed as `1000`. Your problem is that

```
parseFloat("1 000")
```

gives

```
1
```

In that case, strip the spaces :

```
var currentAmountAsNumber = parseFloat(currentAmount.toString().replace(/[ ,]/g,''))
```

But having a test case would probably let us simplify that.